# Challenge: Creating Compilable Permutations Function

Tags: compile, combinatorics, permutation

As *Mathematica*'s implemented `Permutations` function is not compilable, I tried to write my very own `Permutations` implementation, called `PermutationsNew`, which I want to compile later on. Unfortunately the only implementation I came up with so far uses recursive programming and looks like this:

```
PermutationsInternal = Function[{list, listfixed}, If[Length[list] == 1,
                                Join[listfixed, list],
                                Table[PermutationsInternal[Drop[list, {i}],
                                      Append[listfixed, list[[i]]]], {i, Length[list]}] ]];
PermutationsNew[list_] := Flatten[PermutationsInternal[list, {}], Length[list] - 2]
```

The implementation seems to work fine, but because of the recursive structure, I cannot come up with any approach that can be compiled, because *Mathematica* has trouble compiling the lists encountered in `PermutationsInternal`.

Does anybody have an idea on how to compile the above approach or can offer me an idea for a different compilable solution?

Comment: What is your use case?  With permutations there's a danger of running out of memory before running out of time ...

Comment: I mean, `Permutations` returns a packed array, so it is memory efficient.  `ByteCount@Permutations[Range[11]] // AbsoluteTiming` gives 1.8 seconds and 3.5 GB on my machine.  There's clearly not enough memory to go to $n=12$ and 1.8 seconds is still not that slow for a one-time computation.

Comment: memory usage should not be a problem, the lists I need to permute usually do not contain more than 8 items, but the permutation process would be part of a highly optimized and compiled function that in return has to be applied frequently in the computation process

Comment: In that case how about precomputing permutations once, `perm = Permutations@Range[4]`, then applying these precomputed permutations to your actual list, as in `{a,b,c,d}[[#]]& /@ perm`?  This application can be done using a compiled function much more easily.  If your list has the same integers as `Range[1,n]`, then the permuted lists will be equivalent to `perm`, except in a different order.  So this will probably make sense if your list has other numbers than `{1,2,3,4}` in some order.

Comment: I think that's a good solution. I will try this out soon, but I do not see why it should not work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps related in some way http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10678/using-compile-to-speed-up-function-with-permutationproduct

Answer (score 9):

As a proof of concept, I present here a straightforward implementation of Don Knuth's ["Algorithm L"](http://books.google.com/books?id=IkuEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT483) for generating permutations in lexicographic order:

```
cPermutations = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
                        Module[{n = Length[list], p = Sort[list], pbag, j, k},
                               pbag = Internal`Bag[Most[{1}]];
                               While[True,
                                     Internal`StuffBag[pbag, p, 1];
                                     j = n - 1;
                                     While[j > 0 && p[[j]] >= p[[j + 1]], j--];
                                     If[j == 0, Break[]];
                                     k = n;
                                     While[p[[j]] >= p[[k]], k--];
                                     p[[{j, k}]] = p[[{k, j}]];
                                     p = Take[p, j] ~Join~
                                         Take[p, {n, j + 1, -1}]];
                               Partition[Internal`BagPart[pbag, All], n]],
                        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

It gives the same results as `Permutations[]`:

```
cPermutations[Range[9]] === Permutations[Range[9]]
   True

l = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7};
cPermutations[l] === Permutations[l]
   True
```

**Unfortunately**, this implementation is ***quite a lot slower*** than `Permutations[]`. There might be a few tricks to speed this up further, but considering that `Permutations[]` has been a built-in function since the first version, I am skeptical that it can be outdone by a compiled function like this one.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, because unfortunately, recursion is not supported by the compiler. We can see this with a very simple example: the Fibonacci sequence. Recall that one can write a recursive pure function by using slot `#0` to refer to the function itself. Hence:

```
With[{fibonacci = Function[Null, If[#1 == 1 || #1 == 2, 1, #0[#1 - 1] + #0[#1 - 2]]]},
 Compile[{{i, _Integer, 0}}, fibonacci[i]]
]
```

**However, this input crashes the kernel.** It takes some seconds for this to happen, so I expect it is caused by the attempts of the compiler to unroll the recursion, resulting in a stack overflow. Your function produces the same outcome if written in this way, but I felt that a more minimal example (without e.g. `Append`) would be helpful in demonstrating the source of the problem.

Comment: "recursion is not supported by the compiler", this is not entirely true. If you execute this line _twice_, you get a recursive library call that avoids `MainEvaluate`: `fib = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
  If[n == 1 || n == 2, 1, 
   fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
    "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False}, CompilationTarget -> "C"]`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer it is true that one can use LibraryLink functions to get around the limitation, but I would argue that the existence of the opcode 42 mechanism does not equate to support for recursion *per se*. At that point it is easier to just write the function in C and not use the *Mathematica* compiler at all.