# Custom Table, for iterating over permutations

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation, iterators

It is common that I iterate over all permutations of 1,2...,n, either by making a table or performing a sum.

Instead of creating the set of all permutations, it would be better to iterate over them.
Of course, it would be convenient for me if there was such a way to automatically do this iteration construct. The following is my attempt;

```
Clear[PermutationsTable];
SetAttributes[PermutationsTable, HoldFirst];
PermutationsTable[body_, {pi_Symbol, n_Integer}] := Module[
   {iter},
   Needs["Combinatorica`"];
   Table[
    Block[{pi = Combinatorica`UnrankPermutation[iter, n]},
     body
     ]
    , {iter, n!}]
   ];
```

Then one just does `PermutationsTable[ First[pi], {pi, 4}]` to say extract the first element out of all permutations of size 4.

**Now, what improvements can be made for the code?** Also, for the `Sum` version, I assume one can simply replace Table with Sum in the code.
There should be some way to color the iteration argument as how the variables work for
the build-in Table.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1283) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98908)?